# How to enable HP pavillon dv9000 pci express card

Tags: 10.10, hardware, 64-bit, hp

I Have an HP Pavillon dv9000, I recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 x64 on this laptop, everything works very very fine, but when I insert my eSATA pci express card in the slot, and attach my external eSATA HD nothing happen and it's clear the HD is not recognized.

I removed the card, tailed `/var/log/syslog` then I plugged in the card, but nothing was been added to the log.

An idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an esata card that sort of didn't work. I need you to follow these steps, and then update your question with the information:

`lspci` in a terminal and add the hardware information to your question. Here's mine as an example:

`02:01.0 RAID bus controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3124 PCI-X Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)`

The I need to to tail the system log file:

`sudo tail -F /var/log/syslog`

Now, while keeping that terminal open, plug in your drive, it should scroll a bunch of stuff; add that to your question.

Comment: I made what you suggest but nothing happen. I plug out the card, I done the tail, then I plugged in the card, but nothing has been added to the log.

Comment: Whoops sorry, misread, does anything happen when you plug the drive in?

Comment: sorry for my state of beginner with ubuntu! But, when I was on 10.04 the card was hot pluggable (I don e on a Lenovo laptop and everything worked fine)

Comment: Right, my mistake, what happens when you plug a drive in? (Add what happens when you do that to your question)

Comment: Also, I still need the lspci information when you have the card plugged in (add it to your question too)

Comment: The same, I plugged in the card, after I plug the external HD with the esata connector, but nothign happens. The Drive works fine and on the Lenovo laptop it worked. My fear is that Ubuntu 10.10 on this dv9000 laptop doesn't handle the pciexpress at well

Comment: @Hoghweed, run `lspci` in terminal with the esata card plugged in, then copy-paste the output of that into your question via an edit.

Comment: maybe dmesg talks to you, try running this and plug it in **watch "dmesg | tail -10"**